# C#: Select datarow from datarow

Tags: c#, select, datatable, datarow

How can I select datarow from another datarow?
Datarow have [id,name,surname,phone,email,status]
I need get datarow with [id, name] or [id,name,phone]

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
//row have columns [id,name,surname,phone,email,status]
            switch ((Int32)row["status"])
            {
                case 1:
                    someFunction(row.[SELECT id,name]);  //need here datarow with colums id,name
                    break;
                case 2:
                    someFunction(row.[SELECT id,name,phone]);  //need here datarow with colums id,name,phone
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What? Sorry. Come again.

Comment: It's difficult to understand exactly what you're asking, and this question is coming very close to "can you please write this code for me", which is typically not allowed on SO. Please revise your question to be more clear about what you mean.

Comment: You dont need write code for me. Question is simple: How get "DataRow with columns id,name" from "DataRow with columns id,name,phone..."
If where is no way to do that - it will be the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass it like this

```
someFunction(row["id"] + "," row["name"]);
```

and your some function should take string like this

```
Public Foo someFunction(string str)
{
  //Here split str with comma (,)
}
```

Comment: There is no way to get DataRow ?
Function take a DataRow... or I need create new DataRow and add [id,name and ect.] ?

Comment: It is like asking integer within an integer.

Comment: DataRow have columns, there is no way to remove or select by colums?

Comment: In your case you are keeping logic in 2 places. First in switch statement and other in your function someFunction. My solution will be to keep logic in one place. i.e. in your function.

Comment: I send all dataRow data to function. In function create switch by row["status"]. Thnx for answers...

Comment: @Alex: That's what I was taking about. Your logic remains in one place.

Answer (score 0):

For Selecting rows in datatable you could use [`DataTable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
//select rows having status = 1
DataRow[] rows1 = dt.Select("status = 1");
//select rows having status = 2
DataRow[] rows2 = dt.Select("status = 2");
```

Or you could use overloaded function to deal with different rows.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
     int iRowStatus = Convert.ToInt32(row["status"]);
     int iId = Convert.ToInt32(row["id"]);
     string sName = row["name"].ToString();
     string sPhone = row["phone"].ToString();

     switch (iRowStatus)
     {
        case 1:
           someFunction(iId,sName);  
           break;
        case 2:
           someFunction(iId,sName, sPhone);  
           break;
      }
} 

private void someFunction (int iId, string sName)
{
     //do something
}


private void someFunction (int iId, string sName, string sPhone)
{
     //do something
}
```

Comment: You can send `DataRow` as parameter. Then you have to get values from row like above.

Comment: It is better to have overloaded function. When you will pass on `DataRow` you will have to look for `status` again.

Comment: Check `DataTable.Select` option you have to select rows.

Comment: DataRow is part of datatable. Columns exist in datatable. So you cannot remove or filter columns from datarow.

Answer (score 0):

The someFunction should be defined as:

```
DataRow someFunction(DataRow row,String columns){
return row.Table.DefaultView.ToTable(false,columns).Rows[row.Table.Rows.IndexOf(row)];
}
```

Note that this function can be optimized by caching the filtered datatable.